# How to convert string to byte array in Nodejs like Java

Tags: java, node.js

We need 2 lines of code to convert string to byte array in Java. How to do same in Nodejs

Below is java code :

```
    String secretKey = "j3u8ue8xnrhsth59";
    byte[] keyValue = secretKey.getBytes();
    System.out.println(keyValue);
```